# cannot use import statement outside a module error

Tags: javascript, import

So I have a file and it contains a function

```
const registerUsernameValidation = (username, n_patt) => {
    if (username.val() == "" || username.val().length > 12 || username.val().length < 3) {
        username.addClass("border-danger");
        $("#u_error").html("<span class='text-danger'>Please Enter A Username</span>");
        status = false;
    } else if (username.val().length > 12) {
        username.addClass("border-danger");
        $("#u_error").html("Please Enter A Username With A Length Less Than 12");
        status = false;
    } else if (username.val().length < 3) {
        username.addClass("border-danger");
        $("#u_error").html("Please Enter A Username With A Length Greater Than 3");
        status = false;
    } else if (!n_patt.test(username.val())) {
        username.addClass("border-danger");
        $("#u_error").html("Please Enter A Valid Username, Only Letters And Numbers");
        status = false;
    } else {
        username.removeClass("border-danger");
        $("#u_error").html("");
        status = true;
    }
}

export {registerUsernameValidation};
```

my main.js:

```
import { registerUsernameValidation } from "./validation.js";

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#register_form").on("submit", function() {
        var username = $("#username");
        var email = $("#email");
        var pass1 = $("#password1");
        var pass2 = $("#password2");
        var type = $("#usertype");
        var n_patt = new RegExp(/^(?![0-9]*$)[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/);
        var e_patt = new RegExp(/^[a-z0-9_-]+(\.[a-z0-9_-]+)*@[a-z0-9_-]+(\.[a-z0-9_-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,4})$/);
        
        registerUsernameValidation(username, n_patt);
    });
});
```

and for some reason I still get an error
Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

Comment: Is your `main.js` file marked with `type=module`? You can google that error message and get many, many explanations.

Comment: @Pointy how do you do that? I am not using node.

Comment: `<script type=module>` — it will not work in IE11 (or any older IE version of course)

Comment: @Pointy i am using import though and I am in a js file not an html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Using in Node.js

Add `"type": "module"` to your package.json. This will tell node that `import` will be used to import files instead of `require`.

### Using in browser

Add a [`type="module"`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#attr-type) attribute to your `<script>` tag.

Comment: I updated the answer to include steps for using modules in browser.

Comment: one question its a javascript file where do I put my script tag in the import

Comment: Don't you already have an html file with a script tag?

Comment: Yes I changed it but it still returns in an error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234263/discussion-between-danny-kim-and-programmerraj).